# How to pull an image being added to cart dynamically

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, product-images, addtocart, dynamic

```
<?php
$count = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();  //get total items in cart
$total = $count > 0 ?  Mage::helper('core')->currency($this->helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(), true, false) : '$0.00';
$cartUrl = $count > 0 ? Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl() : "#";
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
?>
<a href="<?php echo $cartUrl ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span>Cart</span> (<?php echo $count ?>) <?php echo $total ?> <b class="caret"></b></a>
<?php if(!empty($cartItems)): ?>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="cart-dropdown">
<?php foreach ($cartItems as $item): ?>
    <li>
        <div class="cart-item-link">
            <div class="item-cart-content clearfix">
                <div class="item-cart-image">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/item-cart.png') ?>" class="img-responsive center-block">
                </div>
                <div class="item-cart-text">
                    <h4 class="item-cart-title"><?php echo $item->getName() ?></h4>
                    <p><?php echo $item->getQty(); ?> x <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($item->getPrice(), true, false) ?></p>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/delete', array('id' => $item->getId() )); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Remove Item') ?></a>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>    
    <li>
        <div class="cart-subtotal-link">
            <div class="item-cart-content clearfix">
                <div class="item-cart-image">
                    <h4>Order Subtotal</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="item-cart-text">
                    <span class="item-cart-price"><?php echo $total ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="cart-btn-container">
            <h5>FREE GROUND SHIPPING on JUICERS & BLENDERS »</h5>
            <div class="btn-container clearfix">
                <a href="https://www.omegajuicers.com/checkout/cart/"><button class="view-shopping-cart menu-cart-btn">View Shopping Cart</button></a>
                <a href="https://www.omegajuicers.com/checkout/onepage/"><button class="checkout-cart menu-cart-btn">Checkout</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is my code. The problem I am having is that I am trying to pull an image from the product that has been added to cart. Here it is just pulling one specific image on my server. How can I make it dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/item-cart.png') ?>" class="img-responsive center-block">
```

With

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item->getProduct(), 'image')->resize(135,135); ?>" class="img-responsive center-block">
```